Using REG_MATCH and REG_REPLACE function in Informatica to replace a Prefix and suffix of a character
I have a Business requirement in infromatica where we have 2 set of Data's like
'HOUSE ACCOUNT - WELLS FARGO - I' where we
have to remove the suffix ' - I ' and another Data
'JR INSURANCE BROKERAGE INC' where I have to remove the prefix 'JR'
currently I am Using the following code and its not working
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sI\s.*') OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sI'),REG_REPLACE(LAST_NAME,'I$','')

 IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sJR\s.*') OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sJR'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'JR','')

Can you Please help me on this ?

can we simplify this problem like this - last two char ='-I' or first two character is 'JR', then replace them with empty space? if yes, then you can use simple SUBSTR and REPLACECHR(). am i missing something?

@KoushikRoy well the requirement is to accomplish this using an expression transformation and not with an SQL override

There is no attempt to remove any hyphen here. And if you want to remove "- I" as suffix, why do you test for an infix with '.*\sI\s.*'?

@trincot Can you Please guide me on how to re alter the code so that the condition is met ?

Can you explain what is holding you back to remove that infix test, and to include a hyphen in your test as per your requirement? I don't understand why you are using that code, when it is obvious there was no attempt to test for a hyphen at all.

@trincot We are getting a source Data as HOUSE ACCOUNT - WELLS FARGO - I , were the customer wants the - I to be removed at the end  . I tried using this expression
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sI\s.')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sI'),REPLACESTR(LAST_NAME,'I','') and it removes the 'I' alone and loads the Data as 'HOUSE ACCOUNT - WELLS FARGO ' .  In order to remove the hyphen I re altered the code as
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sI\s.')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sI'),REPLACESTR(LAST_NAME,'-I$','') but it is still not working .

Why do you want the infix condition? Do you have any such requirement?

Yes the requirement is such that we have to do a pattern match and then replace the Value . We are doing this using the Informatica tool and not directly through an Sql .

If you have also an infix requirement, then please state that in the question, where you currently only mention the suffix requirement for "- I", and a prefix requirement for "JR". You didn't mention any infix requirement. Moreover, your question shows no attempt for testing the hyphen. Also the code you shared has 8 opening parentheses and  6 closing parentheses. This cannot run.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am sorry for that , Can you please help me with this situation on how to remove the '-I'  and 'JR' from the string using the expression mentioned above ?

This is related to your previous question. Please try to break this down and do some proper testing.

Build a transformation with REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME, 'YOUR-CODE-HERE')
Test the results
Add another, separate port with REG_REPLACE(LAST_NAME,'YOUR-CODE-HERE','')
Test it.
Once you're satisfied with the results, pull it all together in one expression
Test it.

If at any point you're stuck, please provide your code, test ressults and question. We're happy to assist. However please do not expect the members of this community to write the code for you.
Best of luck with your efforts!
